# Swift 1.2 not working with same function name and different parameter

Tags: swift

I have 2 functions with the same name but different parameters.

The first one accepts as a parameter a function that accepts 2 doubles and returns one.

The second one accepts as a parameter a function that accept 1 double and returns one. This works in Swift 1.1, tested on Xcode 6.1.1, however in Swift 1.2, tested on Xcode 6.4 (beta), this doesn't work and gives me this error:

> Method 'performOperation' with Objective-C selector 'performOperation:'
>   conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector

What can I do that this can work, and why that is happening?
I know that I can do the square root another way then it is here,but I want to know whats the problem.

***Edit***

```
 @IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
        let operation = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInMiddleOfTypingANumber{
            enter()
        }
        switch operation{
        case "×" : performOperation {$0 * $1}
        case "÷" : performOperation {$1 / $0}
        case "+" : performOperation {$0 + $1}
        case "−" : performOperation {$1 - $0}
        case "√" : performOperation {sqrt($0)}
        default : break
        }
    }

    func performOperation(operation : (Double,Double) -> Double){
        if operandStack.count >= 2{
            displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(),operandStack.removeLast())
            enter()
        }
    }

    func performOperation(operation : Double -> Double) {
        if operandStack.count >= 1{
            displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
            enter()
        }
    }
```

Comment: post methods and line that error is on to help people answer

Comment: @WillM.It is enough ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot overload methods that Objective-C can see, because Objective-C has no overloading:

```
func performOperation(operation : (Double,Double) -> Double){
}
func performOperation(operation : Double -> Double) {
}
```

(The fact that this was allowed in Swift before Swift 1.2 was in fact a bug; Swift 1.2 closed the loophole and fixed the bug.)

Simple solution: hide these methods from Objective-C. For example, declare them both `private`.

More tricky solution: change the name by which Objective-C sees one of them. For example:

```
func performOperation(operation : (Double,Double) -> Double){
}
@objc(performOperation2:) func performOperation(operation : Double -> Double) {
}
```

Or, new in Swift 2.0, you can hide one or both of them from Objective-C without going so far as to make it private:

```
@nonobjc func performOperation(operation : (Double,Double) -> Double){
}
func performOperation(operation : Double -> Double) {
}
```

Comment: You could also give them different Obj-C selector names using `@objc(...)` right?

Comment: @nielsbot Yes, it would suffice to give just one of them a different objc name. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: This actual example made it into the WWDC 2015 session 401 video. What are the chances?

Comment: That's funny--I'll have to look for that

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :)