# Cannot have a function with same name as parameter type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mailcore2

I have a class that conforms to an Objective-C protocol and has a function with the same name as one of it's parameter types.

```
class MessageDataController: NSObject, MCOHTMLRendererDelegate {
    @objc func MCOAbstractMessage(msg: MCOAbstractMessage!, canPreviewPart part: MCOAbstractPart!) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

This causes Xcode to give the error

> "Use of undeclared type 'MCOAbstractMessage'"

for using `MCOAbstractMessage` as both the function name and a parameter type. It doesn't give an error if I change the function name to `abstractMessage` or similar. I think the issue is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685335/swift-1-2-not-working-with-same-function-name-and-different-parameter) and/or [this issue](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/issues/1062) but am unsure how to resolve. My project's header file is correctly configured to use `MailCore2`.

Tried changing the declaration to:

```
@objc(MCOAbstractMessage:canPreviewPart:) func abstractMessage(msg: MCOAbstractMessage!, canPreviewPart part: MCOAbstractPart!) -> Bool
```

which gives the error

> "~/src/project/MessageDataController.swift:11:52: Objective-C method 'MCOAbstractMessage:canPreviewPart:' provided by method 'abstractMessage(*:canPreviewPart:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'MCOAbstractMessage(*:canPreviewPart:)' in protocol 'MCOHTMLRendererDelegate'"

Comment: You really shouldn't use uppercase for method names...

Comment: Not my choice. The protocol defines this particular method as `- (BOOL) MCOAbstractMessage:(MCOAbstractMessage *)msg canPreviewPart:(MCOAbstractPart *)part;`. See [here](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/src/objc/abstract/MCOHTMLRendererDelegate.h) for the protocol I'm trying to implement.

Comment: Your first method is implemented right. But the Swift code cannot understand `@class MCOAbstractMessage` defined in Objective C.

Comment: Would there be a way to achieve it without changing the ObjC code? For example, is there a way to redefine the Swift<->ObjC name mapping?

Comment: Could you take a look at the following? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html and look for NS_SWIFT_NAME. You might be interested in applying a patch to MailCore2 and send a pull request to the project. Thanks!

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Will do. Thanks!

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Unfortunately, the NS_SWIFT_NAME macro only applies to class factory methods.

Comment: @Kametrixom: The casing is correct for ObjC. Prefixes are generally capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

This may be solved by using the fully-qualified type name in the parameter list. I'm not familiar with the library you are using, but the suggestion below assumes that the type `MCOAbstractMessage` is declared in a module called `MCO`. Prepend `MCO.` to the type name.

```
class MessageDataController: NSObject, MCOHTMLRendererDelegate {
    @objc func MCOAbstractMessage(msg: MCO.MCOAbstractMessage!, canPreviewPart part: MCOAbstractPart!) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

I tested this by adding a method called `Array` to one of my classes. Sure enough it threw compiler errors everywhere else that I had used `Array` as a type. I prefixed all of those as `Swift.Array` and all was well.

If you want a shorter version, use a typealias,

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Where would I find the module declaration, if any? [Here](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/tree/master/src/objc) is the library I'm working with.

Comment: Check out this reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: As a followup, typealias doesn't work because I still get the `Use of undeclared type` error mentioned in my post, as well as a `Type alias circularly references itself` error.